How to merge multiple functions to dynamically create a single table of data?
I have a spreadsheet of financial transactions. The Columns headers are (A) Date, (B) Category, (C) Subcategory, (D) Description, (E) Amount.
I have a separate budgeting spreadsheet that contains a table of average transaction amount by category per month and whose column 1 header is category and each subsequent column header is the month of the year, and each cell is the amount spent that month.
Using GROUP BY, if I use the following QUERY I can get a list of all transactions summarized by unique category:
=query('FinancialTransactions'!A1:E, "SELECT B, SUM(E) where E < 0 group by B ")
If I use the following QUERY I can get the same data grouped by category for a specific month:
=query('FinancialTransactions'!A1:E, "SELECT SUM(E)  where A <= date '2022-01-31'  AND A >= date '2022-01-01'  AND E < 0  AND C = 'New York' AND B = 'Grocery'  group by B label SUM(E) ''")
Ultimately, what I'd like to accomplish is dynamically create the unique list of categories in column 1 either using UNIQUE or inside a QUERY and then dynamically create month and amount for each month across, so that it looks like this over the span of a date range (ie twelve months):



A header
Jan
Feb
Etc
etc




Grocery
212.23
205.11
etc



Utility
405.19
400.44
etc




Im brand new to spread sheets and google sheets in general, but I do know SQL. Regardless, I feel like there is a more efficient way to do this so I'm not manually entering data into the budget sheet.

You can use QUERY with the PIVOT clause, like this:
=query(A1:E, "SELECT B, SUM(E) WHERE A is not null GROUP BY B PIVOT MONTH(A)+1",1)



Nice! Do you know what I can use to format the date so the column header is Jan, or Jan-YYYY?
